# Exponential distribution in Python

Tags: python, exponential-distribution

What's the easiest way to draw a random number from an exponential distribution in Python?

Comment: Do you have a copy of a computer science textbook that cover this?  Have you looked at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Generating_exponential_variates?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[random.expovariate](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html?highlight=random#random.expovariate) of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `random` module. For more information, consult [its documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html).